# jwplayer stalling after ad finishes playing

Tags: jwplayer

I'm having an issue where the jwplayer stalls after an ad plays, it just shows the last frame of the ad's video and has the loading image which spins indefinitely.  I have turned on debugging and found that something happens on or after the player gets reset because the last two debug entries are:

- NetworkResource: HTTP call complete (to complete) - 42 bytes loaded
- Debuggable: Resetting the player - closing any active overlays, notices

I have tried to trace/debug the runtime JS and the events onComplete and then onBeforePlay get called, in the onBeforePlay even the proper file shows up (`jwplayer('container').getPlaylistItem()['file']`) of the video file that is supposed to be played after the ad video.

On a rare occasion the video file does get loaded after the ad plays, at which time the "Resetting the player..." line is followed by two more debug lines in the console:

- NetworkResource: HTTP call complete (to complete) - 42 bytes loaded
- Debuggable: Resetting the player - closing any active overlays, notices
- Debuggable: Duration metadata received for active clip - metadata duration is 63.4
- Debuggable: Not adjustin gthe ad stream metadata - deriveShowDurationFromMetaData = false

Any thoughts or ideas on what could be causing this or how to further research what could be causing this?

Thank you,
Kate

Comment: Please provide a link so we can debug this, thanks.

Comment: I will put it on an accessible server shortly.

Comment: Thank you Ethan, the link is http://pisz.ca/ad_test/ .

Comment: PS... when viewing the traffic/requests in fiddler, I can see the mp4 movie is requested, it's just not loaded into the jwplayer because something is stuck.

Comment: A couple things here. This file is returning a 404 not found - http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/crossdomain.xml, you are using the old OVA version, the latest RC is available on the developer site - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/ova, and you should upgrade from 5.9 to 5.10, which can be done by contacting us for the licensed player here - http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/, select general inquiry.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have eliminated the crossdomain.xml error by referencing to a different video.  As to upgrading to jwplayer 5.10, the browser we are stuck working with doesn't support HTML5, so is there still a point to upgrading?

Comment: Yes, 5.10 has some fixes in it over 5.10. You really should update to the latest build of OVA though from the OVA developer Wiki. That is a must.